# How to create custom form area with multiple touchable areas?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

I want to create custom touchable area from .png with a few touchable areas. I want to recognize which was touched. I find a solution only for custom area recognition, which based on Alpha recognition:

```
extension UIView {
func alphaFromPoint(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
   var pixel: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
   let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   let alphaInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
   let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(&pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, alphaInfo)
   CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

   self.layer.renderInContext(context)

   let floatAlpha = CGFloat(pixel[3])
   return floatAlpha
} 
}
```

This only help me for recognize touch event on custom area. I think I can divide the area on several parts for needed area, but it will be correct only for one device size.

Comment: why not add overlays to the parts of the image where you want it to be touched and then add tap gestures on it

Comment: I think about this, but how can I bind those part to the relevant parts of a image for different screen size?